# How can I customize the output of the main menu in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I am new to Drupal and I would like to customize the output of the main menu. Can anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?  The ideal scenario is a pre-packaged module that retrieves the data from the database and allows me to output it as I want. Alternatively, I can code if necessary.

The default menu output is this:

```
<h2>Main menu</h2>
<ul id="main-menu" class="links inline clearfix">
    <li class="menu-449 first"><a href="/sdnn_drupal/?q=node/add" title="">Section 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-452"><a href="/sdnn_drupal/?q=node/add" title="">Section 2</a></li>
    <li class="menu-453"><a href="/sdnn_drupal/?q=node/add" title="">Section 3</a></li>
    <li class="menu-451"><a href="/sdnn_drupal/?q=node/add" title="">Section 4</a></li>
    <li class="menu-454"><a href="/sdnn_drupal/?q=node/add" title="">Section 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

The output that I need is:

```
<ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li><span>Section 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Section 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Section 1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Section 1.3</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Section 1.3.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Section 1.3.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the dhtml_menu module, depending on your layout you may need to do some custom javascripting, but it will do what you're looking for